# KendoUI ObservableArray children being clobbered by KendoUI treeView

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

**Backstory**
I'm using AngularJS/KendoUI and using angular-kendo-ui as a the 'bridge' between the two. I'm using Kendo for it's treeview component and this piece is a client requirement.

What I need to accomplish is
1. draw the tree menu from data provided by a service
2. periodically check each element in this data, and update a 'disabled' prop
3. redraw elements in the treeview based on the results from the above step.

**Assumptions**
1. If I want to be able to update the kendo tree view, then I need to use Kendo's observeables
2. I may be using Kendo's ObservableArray incorrectly here.

**The problem**
If I create a new ObservableArray like so

```
  var things = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([{
      text: "Parent 1",
      items: [{text: "Child 1"}, {text: "Child 2"}, {text: "Child 3"}]
  }])
```

`things` be logged to the `console` and the structure is intact.
However, once the treeview is instantiated with this data, further logging of `things` to the console show that the children (items) are no longer present. It is very hard to iterate over and update children if they don't exist!

Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/qJpIvK?p=info, if you view the 'script.js' file and open the console, you should be able to see my issue.

here is the code

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="TreeController">
            <div kendo-tree-view k-options="thingsOptions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
  var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["kendo.directives"]);

  app.controller('TreeController', function($scope, $timeout) {

    var things = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([{
      text: "Parent 1",
      items: [{
        text: "Child 1"
      }, {
        text: "Child 2"
      }, {
        text: "Child 3"
      }]
    }, {
      text: "Parent 2",
      items: [{
        text: "Child 1"
      }, {
        text: "Child 2"
      }, {
        text: "Child 3"
      }]
    }]);

    // should have 3 items
    console.log('preTreeView init', things[1].items);
    $scope.thingsOptions = {
      dataSource: things
    };

    $timeout(function() {
      // the 3 items expected are gone, why?
      console.log('postTreeView init', things[1].items);
    }, 1000);

  });
```

Is this a misuse of ObservableArray and if so, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the TreeView widget turns your `ObservableArray` into a `kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource` http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/hierarchicaldatasource which moves each of the children into `DataSource` objects of their own.

You can navigate them afterward like this:

```
var treeViewWidget = $(".k-treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var dataSource = treeViewWidget.dataSource; // this is a HierachicalDataSource

var parents = dataSource.data(); // Parent1 and Parent2
var parent1 = parents[0];
var doesParent1HaveChildren = parent1.hasChildren; // true

var childrenDataSource = parent1.children; // this is a HierarchicalDataSource
var child1 = childrenDataSource.data()[0]; // this is {text: "Child 1"}
```